# How to correct set work_mem amd max_wal_size in my postgres image

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to set to my postgres image some configuration, need increas work_mem and `max_wal_size`, but faced with error

```
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 315: exec: postgres -c max_wal_size=2GB -c work_mem=2GB: not found
```

varsions

```
Docker version 19.03.8, build afacb8b7f0
docker-compose version 1.23.1, build b02f1306
```

and my docker compose

```
version: '3'
services:

postgres:
    image: postgres:11-alpine
    shm_size: 5g
    command: postgres -c max_wal_size=2GB -c work_mem=2GB
    ports:
        - '5432:5432'
    container_name: 'postgresql_alpine'
    working_dir: /app
    restart: always
    environment:
        POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
        POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
        POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
        LC_COLLATE: 'sv_SE.UTF-8'
        LC_CTYPE: 'sv_SE.UTF-8'
    volumes:
        - ./data/postgresql:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    networks:
        - php
```

and error

```
ivan@ivan-laptop:~/hosts/docker-symfony$ docker logs d30c27661a48
/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 315: exec: postgres -c max_wal_size=2GB -c work_mem=2GB: not found
```

how to correct set work_mem amd max_wal_size in my postgres image?

**RESOLVE**
First I remove dir `data/postgres` and create again, then I removed all

```
docker system prune -a --volumes
```

images and rebuilded and up again

Comment: `work_mem=2GB` is **way** too high.

Comment: how much to be orrect 100mb ?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: line 315: exec: postgres -c work_mem=100mb: not found`

Answer (score 12):

Default postgres Docker image entrypoint takes parameters directly, you should omit `postgres` in the command sequence.

```
version: '3'

services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:12-alpine
    ...
    command: >
      -c work_mem=256MB
      -c maintenance_work_mem=256MB
      -c max_wal_size=1GB
    ...
```